# what is document.cookie="sess="; document.location="/"?

Tags: session-cookies

You log in to an application and the server sets the following cookie:
Set-cookie: sess=ab11298f7eg14;
When you click the logout button, this causes the following client-side script to execute:
document.cookie="sess="; document.location="/"; What conclusion would you draw from this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That they are using session ids stored in a cookie for authorization. When you logout, they reset the value of the cookie named "sess" (the wrong way, they should use a negative expiration date instead of a empty value to delete it). They den redirect you to "/", ie their start page.

Comment: thanks alex you think still it is bad way and hackers can find the information about us? but redirecting to start page do you think still will be information for hackers? or all information is deleted and no way to hack us